# C# how to check if an attribute returns null?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I have following code:

```
            XmlNodeList elemList = xmlFile.GetElementsByTagName("Position");

        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            string posNumber = elemList[i].Attributes["PosNumber"].Value;
            string posGroup = elemList[i].Attributes["PosGroup"].Value;
            string positionsTypeSK = elemList[i].Attributes["PositionTypeSK"].Value;
            string positionCommercialTypeSK = elemList[i].Attributes["PositionCommercialTypeSK"].Value;
            string positionSK = elemList[i].Attributes["PositionSK"].Value;
            string bookingUnitSK = elemList[i].Attributes["BookingUnitSK"].Value;
            string contentComponentCommSK = elemList[i].Attributes["ContentComponentCommSK"].Value;
            string salesAgentPrice = elemList[i].Attributes["SalesAgentPrice"].Value;

            string bundlePositionSK = (elemList[i].Attributes["BundlePositionSK"] != null).ToString();
            string mainPositionSK = (elemList[i].Attributes["MainPositionSK"] != null).ToString();
            //Now I want the value of the attributes or a empty string here


            listOfNames.Add(new ResultNames(positionSK, posGroup, posNumber, positionCommercialTypeSK, bundlePositionSK, mainPositionSK,
                salesAgentPrice, bookingUnitSK, contentComponentCommSK, positionsTypeSK));
        }
        return listOfNames;
```

And I want to check if the attributes, return null.

I tried it with `string bundlePositionSK = (elemList[i].Attributes["BundlePositionSK"] != null).ToString();`

but here it gives me just **true** or **false**.

How can I check every attribute/value if its null? And if its null it should give me an empty string back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
string posNumber = elemList[i].Attributes["PosNumber"]?.Value ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: True, but it wouldn't hurt to explain what this operator does. OP is new to C#.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`:

```
string bundlePositionSK = string.IsNullOrEmpty(elemList[i].Attributes["BundlePositionSK"]?.Value)
                          ? string.Empty
                          : elemList[i].Attributes["BundlePositionSK"].Value;
```

Comment: it says "Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlAttribute' to 'string'" so I just add an ".ToString();?

Comment: `Value` is a string, so it should work. Not sure if you copied it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check it is not null first.

```
string bundlePositionSK =  elemList[i].Attributes["BundlePositionSK"]!=null
                      ? string.Empty
                      : elemList[i].Attributes["BundlePositionSK"];
```

Comment: That won't compile.